# Weird behavior of SELECT DISTINCT statement with RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created a 2TB MySQL RDS, and filled it with 2 tables totaling 1.5TB:

```
+----------+---------------------------+------------+
| Database | Table                     | Size in MB |
+----------+---------------------------+------------+
| stam_db  | owl                       | 1182043.00 |
| stam_db  | owl_owners                |  393695.00 |
```

The instance was set with db.m6g.2xlarge size and 6000 provisioned IOPS.

I ran this query to return the first 10 rows (they are all distinct, no duplicated rows):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT *
FROM    owl
ORDER BY
        name
LIMIT 10;
```

To my surprise, this query has been running for the last 2 hours...
Even more surprising, the "Free Storage Space" AWS metric started to decrease at a rate of 2.2GB/minute:
[image: Free Storage Space metric]

For some reason, Write IOPS suddenly risen to 600-700 per second:
[image: Write IOPS metric]

READ IOPS went even higher, to about 1850 per second:
[image: READ IOPS metric]

This brings total IOPS to around 2400-2500:
[image: Total IOPS metric]

CPU Utilization remained in the low single digits:
[image: CPU Utilization metric]

I have a few questions:

1. Why would a SELECT DISTINCT statement cause such massive writes into the database?
2. Why would the SELECT DISTINCT try to read the entire DB, instead of just the first 10 rows?
3. Why isn't RDS using the 6000 allocated IOPS? The total IOPS are only about 40% of the allocated amount.

For future reference, here are the answers:

Q2) I think I found an explanation at https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/07/17/mysql-disk-space-exhaustion-for-implicit-temporary-tables/ -" The queries that require a sorting stage most of the time need to rely on a temporary table. For example, when you use GROUP BY, ORDER BY or DISTINCT. Such queries are executed in two stages: the first is to gather the data and put them into a temporary table, the second is to execute the sorting on the temporary table." So even regular SELECT with ORDER BY needs to re-read then whole table

Q1) The massive writes are caused by the temporary table created for the query, they can reach 100% of the original table.

Q3) Looks like MySQL code creating the temporary tables simply isn't efficient enough to utilize the entire 6000 IOPS

Comment: LIMIT 10  just return 10 rows as result but seacrh for all the rows  before returning the first 10 rows

Comment: Do you mean that SELECT DISTINCT reads the entire table before returning the requested amount of rows? Does regular SELECT behave this way too?

Comment: yes...  this is the regular behave   .. with distinct clause or without distinct clause  ..  the distinct clause just avoid the duplicated  row in resutl

Comment: Wow... Is there a way to get 10 rows withing re-reading the entire table?

Comment: I think I found an explanation at https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/07/17/mysql-disk-space-exhaustion-for-implicit-temporary-tables/ -" The queries that require a sorting stage most of the time need to rely on a temporary table. For example, when you use GROUP BY, ORDER BY or DISTINCT.  Such queries are executed in two stages: the first is to gather the data and put them into a temporary table, the second is to execute the sorting on the temporary table." So even regular SELECT with  ORDER BY needs to re-read then whole table

Comment: Running ```SELECT name FROM owl_owl LIMIT 10;``` without DISTINCT or ORDER BY indeed returns results immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `EXPLAIN` to analyze your SELECT DISTINCT query. I bet it will include "Using temporary" and/or "Using filesort". With a large enough result set, these queries will use temporary disk space. But the more frequently you run these queries, the more disk space it uses.

I don't know why you use `SELECT DISTINCT *` if the rows are already distinct. This may cause the use of a temporary table unnecessarily.

Ideally your query should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM    owl
ORDER BY
        name
LIMIT 10;
```

Make sure there is an index on the `name` column, so it can skip the "Using filesort" by reading rows in the index order by name.

Why isn't it using the full provisioned IOPS? I would guess because MySQL is constrained by the code that builds temporary tables. It can't fill the temp tables fast enough to saturate a high number of IOPS. Perhaps if you were to run this query concurrently in many threads it would. But maybe not. IMO, provisioned IOPS are pretty much a scam.

Comment: I used ```SELECT DISTINCT *``` simply as an exercise in MYSQL :) I didn't build any indexes, would that help avoid re-reading the entire database? How big can these temporary tables get - Free Storage Space metric decreased by 420GB already - a bit excessive for a table with 1.1TB data in it...

Comment: How can I see the size of these temporary tables?

Comment: The temp table can get as large as a query result set, _for each query_. It's cleaned up when the query finishes, but if you are apt to run multiple queries at a time for concurrent requests, it can exhaust free space quickly.

Comment: Also for the case of `ORDER BY name LIMIT 100` keep in mind the temp table needs to be as large as the result _before_ the LIMIT. Since the query needs to sort all the data before it can figure out which 100 rows to return.

Comment: I really think learning how to use indexes will help you in this case. You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) and the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Comment: Unfortunately the size of temp tables is not available in MySQL. I filed a bug about this in 2014: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74484

Comment: Thank you so much Bill! I will check your presentation!